# Don't Require RubyGems in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do you start ruby 1.9 without rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942748/how-do-you-start-ruby-1-9-without-rubygems)

I have Ruby 1.9.1 installed and by default RubyGems is required.  As such, my load path has all my gems included.  Is there a way to run Ruby 1.9 without having RubyGems required?

Answer (score 6):

Run ruby with the --disable-gems option.