# how do you start ruby 1.9 without rubygems

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I want my app to *not* be able to use any installed gems.  Is there a ruby 1.9 startup parameter or way of doing this programmatically?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: How would your app use any gems unless you tell it to do so? Seems like not adding any `require`-type commands would solve the problem. It also seems like a user invoking the Ruby interpreter could use '`-r`' and force Ruby to load something, whether your code says to or not.

Comment: I want to ensure that I am never using any system gems--only local files, in my run (to prepare my app for distribution).

Comment: [You caused the addition of a Ruby startup parameter](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7184)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ruby --disable-gems
```

is the MRI (1.9) commandline parameter. "It prevents the addition of gem installation directories to the default load path". (The Ruby Programming Language, p. 391)

Edit 25-10-2012: Ruby core had the same idea as @rogerdpack in the comments and added the more verbose `ruby --help` parameter. [Ruby revision!](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7184)

Comment: Flabberghasting that ruby -h doesn't output this, nor offer you a 'verbose' option for it. yikes.

Comment: @rogerdpack Yes that's weird. Reported [as a bug](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7184).

Comment: Jorg W Mittag has a more verbose comment on `--disable-gems` at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3253995/38765

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [rubygems configuration file](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11#page54), I would attempt to hack out `gempath` or `gemhome` to see if you can override (instead of just append to) defaults.

If, for example, setting `gempath` to be empty, or to point to `/dev/null`, prevents using system gems, then that would be the way to go.

The main advantage to this, as I see it, is that your anti-rubygems config file can be passed to ruby 1.9 as a startup parameter (so not coded in), well documented, and checked into your repository.

All of this is, of course, disregarding that rubygems is part of ruby 1.9's standard library - so ruby may choke and die if it can't have access to its gems, depending on how much of ruby's base install requires gem functionality. YMMV.

Comment: that is a fascinating idea--just tweak the gempath in the script. genius!